# Nickelodeon show with a wizard and gifted children leaping from adventure to adventure

Tags: science-fiction, identify-this-tv-show

I'm looking for a show that was on during the early years of Nickelodeon. It was live action and as far as I can remember it had *maybe* Jonathan Harris (Old English-like actor) playing a frail wizard. There were some gifted children that would leap from adventure to adventure.

The show had a sort of Doctor Who for kids feeling. I only caught the show in spots but remember being very addicted to it. I also remember it changing about halfway thru into a what felt like a different but related show.

I only have some vague memories beyond this that really haven't helped on Google like mazes and giant rocks. Looking up Harris on IMDB I can not find anything that resembles this and thus believe I may be wrong on the actor.

I loved this show as a kid and am more than certain that I will never track it down but any more information on it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the specific answer was a show called "[Into the Labyrinth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Labyrinth_%28TV_series%29)" which was a component of the aforementioned "[The Third Eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Eye_%28TV_series%29)". Nickelodeon purchased a series of British Science Fiction and rolled it all together.

"Into the Labyrinth" starred actor "Ron Moody" (which would explain my mistake and why I couldn't locate information on IMDB.)

[An excerpt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcwLnIf4JO8) (and it seems many of the episodes) can be found on YouTube.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you're referring to [The Third Eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Eye_%28TV_series%29).  This was a sci-fi series that aired in the very early days of Nickelodeon. (I remember watching it as a child myself).  It was quite unlike all of the other Nickelodeon programming, and is the only series that I can recall from that Network that fits your description.

I also remember seeing Dr. Who later on and being reminded of The Third Eye.
Also see [here](http://johnnorrisbrown.com/classic-nick/thirdeye/index.htm).